# Error view not rendering in asp.net core (2.2) mvc only previous view is rendering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

In my case error view is getting hit, but it is not getting rendered.

[image]

it is not an ajax request. I am calling that view from ErrorController.

[image]

Comment: How to redirect to error page here ?

Comment: Is this an AJAX request?  If so you'll need to handle the redirect in your javascript, the server can't redirect on an AJAX request.

Comment: No, it is not a ajax request. I am calling it from ErrorController as above.

Comment: The original call that causes the error seems to be made to the api controller.  Without knowing the structure of your project it's hard to tell but if you're calling an api (most likely an AJAX call)  then the redirect to a view wouldn't work the way you're expecting, unless you have javascript code setup to render the contents of the error view you would receive from the AJAX request.

Comment: After looking at the first screenshot again, it is definitely an AJAX call that's throwing the error.

Comment: You were absolutely right here. I just found out there is an ajax request that is failing. I need to handle the same in Js now. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: In the past I've used a custom JsonResponse class with two booleans IsError and IsRedirect and a Results string property that holds your data serialized as JSON.  If you encounter an error in the controller you can send the IsError back set to true, same with redirect (in your current case) and if everything works just read your data from the Results object.  On the JS side I use custom handler that looks for IsError and IsRedirect first, handling them if necessary, then moves on to parsing the data that was originally requested from the Results string.